# Roomba 500 series installation problem

Tags: ros, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to install roomba_500_series in a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric, which comprises the turtlebot.eu laptop.

The problem I am facing is that the Source: svn http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/unstable/roomba_robot no longer works.

Can someone point me out to the correct source?

Regards,

CG

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27755/roomba-500-series-installation-problem/) by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, it always helps to copy-paste complete error messages. 'no longer works' is not really informative. See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support) for guidelines.

Here at TUM, we also have a couple of EU turtlebots and decided not to use the roomba_500_series node because it has some problems that are really critical for us (e.g. not having a watchdog to stop the robot when no command is received for some time, different topic layout than the original turtlebot, ...). Instead, we made a few patches to turtlebot_node to make it work with the roombas. The patches are already upstream and should be in the newest release of the turtlebot stack. You can bring the robot up by using this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" name="turtlebot_node" output="screen">
    <rosparam>
      robot_type: roomba
      publish_tf: true
      has_gyro: false
    </rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

You can also change the minimal.launch file in the package turtlebot_bringup to set the above node parameters. But don't forget to remove robot_pose_ekf in that case since the EU turtlebots don't have a gyro Then Willow Garage's original turtlebot apps should all work.

**EDIT:** Links to our patches:

- https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/115 (applied)
- https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/116 (applied)
- https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/117 (applied)
- https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/118 (applied)
- https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/121

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) on 2012-02-16**:
Dear Lorenz, I also belong in TUM. Which is your Institute?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-16**:
Computer science, our group is the Intelligent Autonomous Systems Group (http://ias.in.tum.de).

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-02-16**:
these patches are released in turtlebot 0.9